# Tkinter class object issues

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a somewhat complicated Tkinter app that has multiple classes that act as windows. I am only going to share the needed parts to figure out why I am messing up.

I am trying to display a digital clock on the start page above some buttons.

```
class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        clock = Label(self, font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
                                  background = 'purple',
                                  foreground = 'white')
        clock.pack()
        self.time()

    def time(self):
        string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
        clock.config(text = string)
        clock.after(1000, time)
```

The error code:    `clock.config(text = string) NameError: name 'clock' is not defined`

I have played around with different things like adding self.clock.config, but I havent figured it out yet.

I just updated it trying to set the clock label as its own function in StartPage.

```
    def time(self):
        string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
        self.clockLabel.config(text = string)
        self.clockLabel.after(1000, time)

    def clockLabel(self):
        clock = Label(self, font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
                      background = 'purple',
                      foreground = 'white')
        clock.pack()
```

in the init, i still have self.time().

**SOLVED**

```
class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        
        self.clockLabel()
        self.time()

    def time(self):
        string = strftime('%H:%M:%S %p')
        self.clock.config(text = string)
        self.clock.after(1000, self.time)

    def clockLabel(self):
        self.clock = Label(self, font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
                      background = 'purple',
                      foreground = 'white')
        self.clock.pack()
```

[![Picture of working clock][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPMl4.png

Comment: try two things. 1: Make sure you use `self` everywhere 2: set clock in the init function as `null` and use another function to set it to a label

Comment: When I add self. to everything it says that clock doesnt exist in StartPage.

Comment: You need to change all `clock` to `self.clock`.

Comment: 'StartPage' object has no attribute 'clock'

Im going to try the null thing now

Comment: @acw1668 Yes i have done that.

Comment: when I run it now, the error shows that it sees my other functions in StartPage, so I am going to try and do what @JoshSharkey suggested with making the label its own function.

Comment: self.clockLabel.config(text = string)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'config'

Comment: that error means that there is a function somewhere named "clockLabel". Do you have a function called `clockLabel`?

Comment: @JoshSharkey yes. That is the one I just created trying to put the label in its own function. I added it to my question. It is at the bottom.

Comment: give the attribute and the function different name, they cant have the same name

Comment: @JoshSharkey Okay that fixed it. Now it is saying time isnt defined in ` self.clock.after(1000, time)`. If I remove time from that line it runs without errors, but the time doesnt update like a clock.

Comment: I will create an answer that points out the error we found and the solution. Just to keep things clean you will have to make a new separate question if you want to continue getting help. :)

Comment: @JoshSharkey Thank you. I actually just realized what is wrong with it. time is calling itself but I dont have it set up that way currently lol Thats what I get for trying to copypasta a simple clock to a complicated program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here may be related to the name of a variable or function and how they are referenced after they are declared. We performed the following to make the class attributes recognizable

1. Start every class attribute with `self`
2. Initialize the clock attribute with a `None` value and set it to a label in a separate function:

```py
def packClockLabel(self):
    self.clock = Label(self, font = ('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
                      background = 'purple',
                      foreground = 'white')
    clock.pack()
```